# Есть ли сервисы в Украине СНГ для перевода личных средств другому человеку(частному лицу) с помощью API?

Tags: api, платежи, транзакции, банковские-карты, онлайн-коммерция

Нужен способ для перевода своих личных средств другому человеку на карту с помощью API. Пробовал liqPay и wayforpay но там нужно регистрировать свою компанию ТСП (торго сервисное предприятие), нужно иметь свой сайт товары т.д и даже подписывать контракт на получения доступа к api переводам денег. Мне не нужно это все, точно так же как я перевожу деньги своим друзьям и знакомым через интернет банкинг мне нужно так же это сделать только программно. Есть ли какие-то способы это сделать?

Comment: просто ответьте себе на вопрос "что такое api платежной системы или интернет банкинга"?

Comment: Я понимаю это так, что можно делать банковские операции, программно (programmatically) с помощью кода.